# Windows Azure MySQL auto_increment_increment

Tags: mysql, azure

I'm using MySQL on Windows Azure for a PHP app I'm maintaining, and I noticed auto_increment values started to go up by 10. I checked the auto_increment_increment variable and it's set to 10. Setting the variable back to 1 won't work since I don't have admin, obviously.

Is this something I can address in PHP every time I connect? It would be a pain, but if it must be done to keep our numbers reasonable, I'll do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody else having this issue? It's a problem on even the new tables I create.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL in Windows Azure is supported by ClearDB. ClearDB FAQ stated it clearly.

See [ClearDB FAQ](http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq).